# How to change the weight of a font that does not already have different weight variants?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

For example, the font [Secular One](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Secular+One) has only one regular variant, and I'd like to make it bold. I know it's possible in CSS for example, but I couldn't find a way to do it using Jetpack Compose. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of fonts that lack some variants is controlled by [`FontSynthesis`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontSynthesis).

The default `TextStyle.fontSynthesis` is `null`, which [resolved](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/4c4446145411d842b92664677fe628f9a645659f/compose/ui/ui-text/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle.kt#L382) in `FontSynthesis.All` by default, which should synthesize all variants, including bold, so it should work out of the box.

```
val textStyle = TextStyle(
    fontFamily = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.secular_one_regular)
    ),
    fontSynthesis = FontSynthesis.All
)
```